# How to initialize react-native project only for Android?

Tags: android, react-native, cocoapods

Can I initialize react-native app just for android? I executed following on Mac

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

but fails with `cocoapods` related errors.

```
Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
```

Now AFAIK, cocoapods is required for IOS app, and I don't want to spend time investigating those errors.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issues with cocoapods and this is how I was able to do it solely for android.

```
npx react-native init testproject --skip-install

npm install

npx react-native run-android
```